# Pyspark Dataframe: can't resolve calculating mean/avg/agg of Column(inclusive of empty values)

Tags: exception, pyspark, casting, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I am running a Glue Job, and my Dataset contains column with few empty values.As of running crawler on the Dataset, datatype identified as 'double' for the column. 
While replacing empty values with mean of the Column, I am not able to calculate mean as it says mean/avg/agg can only be applied on the numeric column.

And while doing Typecast to IntegerType or DecimalType

```
dataframe_temp = dataframe.withColumn("col_1",dataframe["col_1"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

getting error as :`` AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'CAST(`col_1` AS INT)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast struct<double:double,string:string> to int; ``

However, on manual removal of empty values, mean is working fine.

Could anyone please suggest me, how to replace empty values in the column with the mean of the column.

Comment: How are you loading the data? via csv/json? `null` values can't be inferred as `struct<double:double,string:string>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Imputer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#imputer) estimator to impute missing values. You can use sample code as following-

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1.0, 0),
      (2.0, 0),
      (0, 3.0),
      (4.0, 4.0),
      (5.0, 5.0)
    )).toDF("_c1", "_c2")

val imputer = new Imputer()
    .setStrategy("mean") // supported mode "mean"/"median"
    .setMissingValue(0)
    .setInputCols(Array("_c1","_c2"))
    .setOutputCols(Array("_c1_out","_c2_out")); 

val transformedData = imputer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

> **Please note that- the input columns should be of DoubleType or FloatType.**